# jquery ID selector not working or alerting

Tags: jquery

I am working on a PHP app where I am using jquery to add data to a bootstrap modal.  I am trying to use a jquery selector to get an id of a A tag then do some stuff.  I am having problems getting the selector to do some stuff.

ID of #saveScore is not selectable????

I have put a console log statement in initial click function to verify that the ID is in DOM.  I get a result with this statement.

Here is my Code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=score]', function(){

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var team_name1 = $('#'+id).find('p[data-target=team_name1]').text();
        var team_image1 = $('#team1_image'+id).data('image');
        var team_name2 = $('#'+id).find('p[data-target=team_name2]').text();
        var team_image2 = $('#team2_image'+id).data('image');
        var team1_score = $('#scoreID'+id).find('p[data-target=team1_score]').text();
        var team2_score = $('#scoreID'+id).find('p[data-target=team2_score]').text();

       
       
        $('#team_name1').html(team_name1);
        $('#team_name2').html(team_name2);
        $('#team_image1').removeClass().addClass("col-4 flag ").addClass(team_image1);
        $('#team_image2').removeClass().addClass("col-4 flag ").addClass(team_image2);
        $('#modal_team1_score').val(Number(team1_score));
        $('#modal_team2_score').val(Number(team2_score));

        $('#scoreModal').modal('toggle');
       
        console.log( $('#saveScore'));
    });

  

    $("#saveScore").click(function(){
        alert('test');
        
        
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="#" id="saveScore" class="btn btn-primary">Update Score</a>
 </div>
```

Right now I am just trying to get an alert to pop up showing the #saveScore id is being selected.

Comment: I don't understand the problem - your alert inside the `$('#saveScore').click()` function isn't working? It seems to work fine to me (as long as you're including jQuery): https://jsfiddle.net/ud8wthqf/

Comment: that is where my confusion is coming from.   It seems like it should work just fine.   I have tried code in different browsers also.  Cant seem to see what my issue is.

Comment: Stupid question, but gotta cover my bases.... did you actually click the "Update Score" link; the one the click event listener is attached to? Did you try the jsFiddle link in my other comment? If so, did it work there? Is the modal already present on the page, or is it created on-the-fly with jQuery (if on-the-fly, then likely event delegation is at play - which seems to be answered below)? And, lastly, what's the actual text of the error you see in the console?

Comment: it worked in you fiddle.   Modal is created when page loads.   I have a console.log statement in first part of .on method.  That does return a result.

Comment: I'd be curious, as the first answerer likely is, as to whether replacing `$('#saveScore').click(function() { alert('test'); });` with `$(document).on('click', '#saveScore', function() { alert('test'); });` would work for you. From your comments, it shouldn't, since the `#saveScore` element exists before the click listener is attached to it, but couldn't hurt to be positive that's not the issue. I can't see any other issues with the code - the Fiddle is literally a copy of your posted HTML and your posted JS with jQuery (edge) (I tried with 3.3.1 explicitly, too, and it still worked fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the rest of your code available helped troubleshoot the issue - so thanks for uploading the code required to reproduce the issue.

The problem seems to be with the `.modal-footer` being outside of the `.modal-content` element. It should be nested inside. It's really easy to miss.

Here's the first example from Bootstrap's 4.0 documentation for a modal:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that all three modal content sections (`.modal-header`, `.modal-body`, and `.modal-footer`) are all nested within the `.modal-content` element. If I just open DevTools on your site, and drag the `.modal-footer` element to within the `.modal-content` element, right after `.modal-body`, it seems to act as desired.

My first test was just opening the console and issuing `$('#saveScore').trigger("click");`, which alerted as it was supposed to, so it appeared that the user was unable to click the button - I then used inspect element and hovered over the button, but all Chrome was selecting was the backdrop that the modal creates; it seems the backdrop is in front of (z-index-wise) the `.modal-footer` if it's outside of `.modal-content`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I deleted my modal and copied in a new one from bootstrap website.   Made the ID adjustments and now I can alert by clicking the update button.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add Comment  so I will put answar Here..

I suppose you are adding dynamic content in page 
so Event delegation occurs   you can try this

```
$(document).on("click" , "#saveScore" , function(){
    /*   write your code here*/
   alert('test');

});
```

for more information  visit this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I already have second parameter set "a[data-role=score]" .   I just tried making it "#saveScore" as a third parameter.   No go.  But is that an option?

Comment: if you are changing the content of page  the events are not attached to elements. so you will need to search document for the desired element and attache the event, try  the code above and see what will happen .  the only case make jquary can't find element if one of three( element not in document ) or jquary not included or you added the element to page after  jquary finished loading in page

Comment: I believe saveScore ID is set when page loads.  I have the modal created on initial setup before  any dynamic content added.